# Wordpress paginate_links only working on first page

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination

I'm having an issue with pagination in Wordpress. On my site I'm using the plugin "Daisycon affiliate marketing plugin". I would like display the products that are stored in a custom database table (created by the plugin) on my website.

This is working, but I have an issue with the pagination to work correctly. The stupid thing is that I had it working, but suddenly it seems to be broken and I can't detect what has changed since then.

The problem is that the URLs that are used in the page links, are only correct on the first page. So from there you can nicely navigate to pagenum=2, pagenum=3 etc. However: if you then are on pagenum=2 (for example), all the page links that are shown then are linking to the current page, so to pagenum=2. To see what I mean, see for example http://www.online-medicijnen-bestellen.nl/afslanken-overgewicht/ and try to navigate to the next pages.

Below is my code. Does anyone see what is causing this? I already spent a few hours looking for the problem. I'm a relative newbie when it comes to PHP, so please be gentle and patient ;)

```
<form action="#" method="get" name="sorteer">
<select style="width:200px; float:right; margin-bottom:20px;" name="sortorder" onchange="this.form.submit()">
    <option value="">Sorteer op...</option>
    <option value="title ASC">Titel A-Z</option>
    <option value="price DESC">Hoogste prijs</option>
    <option value="price ASC">Laagste prijs</option>
</select>
</form>

<?php

global $wpdb;
// Nodig om de Wordpress database aan te kunnen spreken

$category   =   get_post_meta(get_queried_object_id(), 'Category', true);
// De property Category van de pagina op basis waarvan de producten van die categorie worden opgevraagd

$sort       =   $_GET['sortorder'];

// Haalt de gekozen optie van sortering op als URL-parameter

if ( empty($sort) ) {
$sortorder = "";
            } else {
$sortorder = "ORDER BY " . $sort;
            }
// Als er geen sorteeroptie is gekozen, sorteer dan niet, anders op basis van de gekozen sorteeroptie

$pagenum = isset( $_GET['pagenum'] ) ? absint( $_GET['pagenum'] ) : 1;
// Haal het pagina-nummer op als URL-parameter

$limit = 20;
// Dit bepaalt het aantal producten per pagina

$offset = ( $pagenum - 1 ) * $limit;
// Dit bepaalt welk product als eerste wordt getoond op de pagina

$prepared   =   $wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM productfeed WHERE category LIKE '$category' ". $sortorder ." LIMIT $offset, $limit");
// Beschermt de query tegen SQL-injectie

$entries = $wpdb->get_results($prepared);
// De SQL-query die de producten ophaalt (van de juiste categorie, op de gekozen manier gesorteerd en op basis van het pagina-nummer de juiste subset)

echo "<table class=product-list>";
foreach($entries as $product) {
    echo "<tr style=cursor:pointer onclick=window.open('".$product->link."')>";
        echo "<td class=buy-image><img src='".$product->image."'/></td>";
        echo "<td class=buy-text><button type=button class=buy-button>€ ".str_replace(".",",",$product->price)."</button><p class=title>".$product->title."</p><p>".$product->description."</p></td>";
    echo "</tr>"; 
}
echo "</table>";
// Hier wordt de tabel opgebouwd die de producten toont

$prepared2  =   $wpdb->prepare("SELECT COUNT(title) FROM productfeed WHERE category LIKE '$category'");
// Beschermt de query tegen SQL-injectie

$total = $wpdb->get_var($prepared2);
// Dit berekent het totaal aantal producten in deze categorie

$num_of_pages = ceil( $total / $limit );
// Dit berekent op basis van het totaal aantal producten en het aantal producten per pagina, hoeveel pagina's er moeten komen

$page_links = paginate_links( array(
'base' => add_query_arg( 'pagenum', '%#%' ),
'format' => '',
'prev_text' => __( '← Vorige', 'aag' ),
'next_text' => __( 'Volgende →', 'aag' ),
'total' => $num_of_pages,
'current' => $pagenum
) );
// Deze array bevat alle pagina-links en bijbehorende attributen

if ( $page_links ) {
echo '<div class="tablenav"><div class="tablenav-pages" style="margin: 1em 0">' . $page_links . '</div></div>';
}
// Als er pagina-links zijn, zet ze dan op deze manier neer.

?>
```

**edit:**

thanks to a tip of a user on a different forum, I'm now using the prepare correct. However this is still not solving my problem. New code is:

```
<form action="#" method="get" name="sorteer">
<select style="width:200px; float:right; margin-bottom:20px;" name="sortorder" onchange="this.form.submit()">
    <option value="">Sorteer op...</option>
    <option value="title ASC">Titel A-Z</option>
    <option value="price DESC">Hoogste prijs</option>
    <option value="price ASC">Laagste prijs</option>
</select>
</form>

<?php

global $wpdb;
// Nodig om de Wordpress database aan te kunnen spreken

$category   =   get_post_meta(get_queried_object_id(), 'Category', true);
// De property Category van de pagina op basis waarvan de producten van die categorie worden opgevraagd

$sort       =   $_GET['sortorder'];
// Haalt de gekozen optie van sortering op als URL-parameter

if ( empty($sort) ) {
$sortorder = "title ASC";
            } else {
$sortorder = $sort;
            }
// Als er geen sorteeroptie is gekozen, sorteer dan niet, anders op basis van de gekozen sorteeroptie

$pagenum = isset( $_GET['pagenum'] ) ? absint( $_GET['pagenum'] ) : 1;
// Haal het pagina-nummer op als URL-parameter

$limit = 20;
// Dit bepaalt het aantal producten per pagina

$offset = ( $pagenum - 1 ) * $limit;
// Dit bepaalt welk product als eerste wordt getoond op de pagina

$prepared   =   $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT * FROM productfeed WHERE category LIKE %s ORDER BY %s LIMIT %d, %d", $category, $sortorder, $offset, $limit);
// Beschermt de query tegen SQL-injectie

$entries = $wpdb->get_results($prepared);
// De SQL-query die de producten ophaalt (van de juiste categorie, op de gekozen manier gesorteerd en op basis van het pagina-nummer de juiste subset)

echo "<table class=product-list>";
foreach($entries as $product) {
    echo "<tr style=cursor:pointer onclick=window.open('".$product->link."')>";
        echo "<td class=buy-image><img src='".$product->image."'/></td>";
        echo "<td class=buy-text><button type=button class=buy-button>€ ".str_replace(".",",",$product->price)."</button><p class=title>".$product->title."</p><p>".$product->description."</p></td>";
    echo "</tr>"; 
}
echo "</table>";
// Hier wordt de tabel opgebouwd die de producten toont

$prepared2  =   $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT COUNT(title) FROM productfeed WHERE category LIKE %s", $category);
// Beschermt de query tegen SQL-injectie

$total = $wpdb->get_var($prepared2);
// Dit berekent het totaal aantal producten in deze categorie

$num_of_pages = ceil( $total / $limit );
// Dit berekent op basis van het totaal aantal producten en het aantal producten per pagina, hoeveel pagina's er moeten komen

$page_links = paginate_links( array(
'base' => add_query_arg( 'pagenum', '%#%' ),
'format' => '',
'prev_text' => __( '← Vorige', 'aag' ),
'next_text' => __( 'Volgende →', 'aag' ),
'total' => $num_of_pages,
'current' => $pagenum
) );
// Deze array bevat alle pagina-links en bijbehorende attributen

if ( $page_links ) {
echo '<div class="tablenav"><div class="tablenav-pages" style="margin: 1em 0">' . $page_links . '</div></div>';
}
// Als er pagina-links zijn, zet ze dan op deze manier neer.

?>
```

Comment: What I notice now by the way, is that the URL in the page links is not complete. For example it shows `<a class="page-numbers" href="/afslanken-overgewicht?pagenum=2">2</a>` instead of `<a class="page-numbers" href="http://www.online-medicijnen-bestellen.nl/afslanken-overgewicht?pagenum=2">2</a>`. Could this have anything to do with it?

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action="#" method="get" name="sorteer">
<select style="width:200px; float:right; margin-bottom:20px;" name="sortorder" onchange="this.form.submit()">
    <option value="">Sorteer op...</option>
    <option value="title ASC">Titel A-Z</option>
    <option value="price DESC">Hoogste prijs</option>
    <option value="price ASC">Laagste prijs</option>
</select>
</form>

<?php

global $wpdb;
// Nodig om de Wordpress database aan te kunnen spreken

$category   =   get_post_meta(get_queried_object_id(), 'Category', true);
// De property Category van de pagina op basis waarvan de producten van die categorie worden opgevraagd

$sort       =   $_GET['sortorder'];

// Haalt de gekozen optie van sortering op als URL-parameter

if ( empty($sort) ) {
$sortorder = "";
            } else {
$sortorder = "ORDER BY " . $sort;
            }
// Als er geen sorteeroptie is gekozen, sorteer dan niet, anders op basis van de gekozen sorteeroptie

$pagenum = isset( $_GET['pagenum'] ) ? absint( $_GET['pagenum'] ) : 1;
add_query_arg( 'pagenum', $pagenum );
// Haal het pagina-nummer op als URL-parameter

$limit = 20;
// Dit bepaalt het aantal producten per pagina

$offset = ( $pagenum - 1 ) * $limit;
// Dit bepaalt welk product als eerste wordt getoond op de pagina

$prepared   =   $wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM productfeed WHERE category LIKE '$category' ". $sortorder ." LIMIT $offset, $limit");
// Beschermt de query tegen SQL-injectie

$entries = $wpdb->get_results($prepared);
// De SQL-query die de producten ophaalt (van de juiste categorie, op de gekozen manier gesorteerd en op basis van het pagina-nummer de juiste subset)

echo "<table class=product-list>";
foreach($entries as $product) {
    echo "<tr style=cursor:pointer onclick=window.open('".$product->link."')>";
        echo "<td class=buy-image><img src='".$product->image."'/></td>";
        echo "<td class=buy-text><button type=button class=buy-button>€ ".str_replace(".",",",$product->price)."</button><p class=title>".$product->title."</p><p>".$product->description."</p></td>";
    echo "</tr>"; 
}
echo "</table>";
// Hier wordt de tabel opgebouwd die de producten toont

$prepared2  =   $wpdb->prepare("SELECT COUNT(title) FROM productfeed WHERE category LIKE '$category'");
// Beschermt de query tegen SQL-injectie

$total = $wpdb->get_var($prepared2);
// Dit berekent het totaal aantal producten in deze categorie

$num_of_pages = ceil( $total / $limit );
// Dit berekent op basis van het totaal aantal producten en het aantal producten per pagina, hoeveel pagina's er moeten komen
$big = 999999999;
$page_links = paginate_links( array(
'base' => str_replace( '/page/'.$big, '?pagenum=%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
'format' => '',
'prev_text' => __( '← Vorige', 'aag' ),
'next_text' => __( 'Volgende →', 'aag' ),
'total' => $num_of_pages,
'current' => max( 1, $pagenum)
) );
// Deze array bevat alle pagina-links en bijbehorende attributen

if ( $page_links ) {
echo '<div class="tablenav"><div class="tablenav-pages" style="margin: 1em 0">' . $page_links . '</div></div>';
}
// Als er pagina-links zijn, zet ze dan op deze manier neer.

?>
```

Comment: Thanks for you reply. Unfortunately this doesn't solve it. What I notice now by the way, is that the URL in the page links is not complete. For example it shows `<a class="page-numbers" href="/afslanken-overgewicht?pagenum=2">2</a>` instead of `<a class="page-numbers" href="http://www.online-medicijnen-bestellen.nl/afslanken-overgewicht?pagenum=2">2</a>`. Could this have anything to do with it?

Comment: and you might also need to use 
add_query_arg( 'pagenum', $pagenum );
 
after the line 
$pagenum = isset( $_GET['pagenum'] ) ? absint( $_GET['pagenum'] ) : 1;

Comment: No luck yet... When I change what you suggest, the page links become for example http://www.online-medicijnen-bestellen.nl/vitaminen-voedingssupplementen/page/2, but then on every page the same products appear.

Comment: my bad that was not meant to be there. will remove that. good luck solving :p